# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'n_splits'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using SKLearn version (0.20.2) following by:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold


grid = GridSearchCV(
    pipeline,  # pipeline from above
    params,  # parameters to tune via cross validation
    refit=True,  # fit using all available data at the end, on the best found param combination
    scoring='accuracy',  # what score are we optimizing?
    cv=StratifiedKFold(label_train, n_splits=5),  # what type of cross validation to use
)
```

But i don't understand why i will get this error:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-03a56044cb82> in <module>()
     10     refit=True,  # fit using all available data at the end, on the best found param combination
     11     scoring='accuracy',  # what score are we optimizing?
---> 12     cv=StratifiedKFold(label_train, n_splits=5),  # what type of cross validation to use
     13 )

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'n_splits'
```

Im already tried `n_fold` but come with the same error result. And also tired to update my scikit version and my conda. Any idea to fix this ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Remove `label_train`; the *first* argument is named `n_splits`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StratifiedKFold takes exactly 3 arguments when initialized, none of which are the training data:

`StratifiedKFold(n_splits=’warn’, shuffle=False, random_state=None)`

So when you call `StratifiedKFold(label_train, n_splits=5)` it thinks you passed `n_splits` twice.

Instead, create the object, then use the methods as described in the example on the sklearn docs page for using the object to split your data:

> get_n_splits([X, y, groups])  Returns the number of splitting
>   iterations in the cross-validator split(X, y[, groups])   Generate
>   indices to split data into training and test set.

Answer (score 0):

StratifiedKFold takes three arguments but you are passing two arguments. See more in sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)

Create StratifiedKFold object and pass it to GridSearchCV as below.

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
skf.get_n_splits(X_train, Y_train)

grid = GridSearchCV(
pipeline,  # pipeline from above
params,  # parameters to tune via cross validation
refit=True,  # fit using all available data at the end, on the best found param combination
scoring='accuracy',  # what score are we optimizing?
cv=skf,  # what type of cross validation to use
)
```